# oracle 11g using index on mixed order by statement

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Creating the table:

> CREATE TABLE TEST1(
>   N1 NUMBER, N2 NUMBER, N3 NUMBER);

So the statement is the following:

> SELECT N3 FROM TEST1
>
> WHERE N1=:bind
>
> ORDER BY N1 ASC, N2 DESC;

insert into the table some data:

> BEGIN
>
> FOR i IN 1..200000
>
> LOOP
>
> INSERT INTO TEST1 VALUES(
>
> ROUND(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1,20000))
>
> ,ROUND(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1,20000))
>
> ,ROUND(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1,20000))
>
> );
>
> END LOOP;
>
> END;

now i have the following indexes:

> CREATE INDEX IND ON TEST1(N1 ASC,N2 DESC);
>
> CREATE INDEX IND ON TEST1(N1 DESC,N2 ASC);

Running execution plans i noticed that a descending index scan has less cost. 
[has same order as in the order by](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfacg.png) 
[has reversed order as in the order by](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rufP.png)

My questions is: does this happen all the time or it's based on the data in the table? (indexed parameters always have to be in the reversed order compared to the order by statement?

Comment: In the query you have not the column used in order by .. then the index is not used for the order by in this case ..if you want a real test you must select the column taht  you need in order by

Comment: They have the same cost now. still is any of them "better"? And why is the cost different if I select an unindexed column

Comment: I have poste a brief anser  hope useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the query you have not the column used in order by .. then the index is not used for the order by in this case ..if you want a real test you must select the column taht you need in order by

If the order is ASC or DESC the cost is the same because the (eventual) index access is the same ..

When you order an index column or an unindex column the costi is different because the info  for the order by is obtained directly from index in the first case otherwise must obtained for the table ..

Comment: The thing is I'm still ordering by an indexed column, I'm just selecting an un-indexed one. Anyways i tried reversing the orders and something unexpected happened: http://pastebin.com/CLaTuuKq On the 1st case I get a high cost (although the columns are inverted) and on the 2nd case I get a much lower cost. So my guess is that it's dependent on the data in the table when selecting a non-indexed column?

Comment: each query is dependent of the data in table  .. (the index is an "order" copy of the data in the table.. you can take a look at this brief doc for a general overview  http://www.asktheoracle.net/how-do-indexes-work-internally-in-oracle.html   and https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/indexes001.htm